# Keep PHP script output to screen with ob_start

Tags: php, laravel, output-buffering, ob-start

I have a script that I need to save its output to a log file.
Till now I had this implementation:

```
ob_start();
   :
   :
$content = ob_get_clean();
Storage::disk('local')->put($logfilePath, $content);
```

The problem is that the script execution time is relatively long, and I need to be able to see the output on screen on the same time.

I was looking for a way to do it, but could not find any elegant solution for it.
Any idea?

**Update:**
I am using Laravel framework, the process is a `Command` instance.

Comment: Are you using a framework? if so please tag it

Comment: Strange approach. You could implement a logging for saving and output directly. If the connection runs a long time, consider using chunked headers.

Comment: Easiest way is with multiple `ob_start(), ob_get_clean()` calls that each log some portion of the request. You would also need chunked headers

Comment: I presume you don't want [ob_get_clean()](https://php.net/ob_get_clean) then, because it empties the buffer (thus the name), but any of the other alternatives followed by a flush. But it's very important to know what exact process is taking too long. If your code does not even produce output while it's running, there isn't too much that output buffer can do about it.

Comment: I just saw it isn't plain PHP but Laravel. I don't use that framework, but I'm positively sure your code should not be issuing `echo` calls in the first place. All frameworks have specific mechanisms to emit output, and echo interferes with that.

Comment: _"the process is a Command instance"_ - so you need to see the output on your console, and not as part of a website? Then what @mousetail said, minus the chunked headers part (because that would only apply if you needed to get the output send to a client via HTTP.)